# Scanpst.exe can run multiple passes as of Outlook 2016 BUT how do you get it to make a backup?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

[This new (10/10/2020) Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/data-files/inbox-repair-tool-scanpst-exe-run-multiple-passes) describes how the **Inbox Repair tool** (Scanpst.exe) can run multiple passes in Outlook 2016 and 365. I've experimented with the command line arguments and cannot get -backupfile to work. It also doesn't seem to have an associated help option (e.g., -h or -?). Anyone have more knowledge or experience with this?

Comment: Two thoughts.  (1) -backupfile must be followed by a path\filename.pst   and (2) make your own backup first.  Scanpst works fine when just executing on the PST file itself.

Comment: Thank you @John. The Note for the -backupfile argument says to include the filename so I tried that, with and without a path. No backup file was created.  I experimented with several variations before submitting this.

Comment: I am not sure how reliable the command line method may be - I do not know. Running SCANPST from an Explorer window runs in GUI mode and does not include a backup in Advanced Options. I suggest backing up manually (I do this routinely) and then scan the live file after (Outlook closed).

Comment: True. But I would like to know how to make the option work, or find out if it's a bug.

Comment: Set up a screenshot of what you did and then use the Microsoft Feedback hub to report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on your comments:

Two thoughts:

(1) -backupfile must be followed by a path\filename.pst

(2) make your own backup first. Scanpst works fine when just executing on the PST file itself.

I am not sure how reliable the command line method may be - I do not know for sure but it should work.

Running SCANPST from an Explorer window runs in GUI mode and does not include a backup in Advanced Options. I suggest backing up manually (I do this routinely) and then scan the live file (Outlook closed).

I trust this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. -backupfile does work. I should have included the same path for the backup file that I used for the target pst file. My apology and appreciation to @John.

Comment: I posted an answer and hope you will acknowledge.

Comment: Right you are. And thank you for your help.